# Поиск в json Совпадений python

Tags: python, json, python-2.x, python-2.7

Доброго времени суток! Как проверить ники игроков и если найдено совпадение по нику увеличить счетчик побед\поражений, либо если нету в json такого игрока добавить его. Есть ли возможность сделать что-то вроде

```
if nick not in data:
  #добавляем в json
else:
  # увеличить счетчик побед\поражений
```

Или только перебирать все и проверять на совпадение и, если совпадения не было, добавлять отдельно?

```
[{"nick": "player1", "win": 0, "lose": 0},{"nick": "player2", "win": 0, "lose": 0}]
```

Comment: Вам необходимо сделать regex, если не знаете как это сделать напишите мне, а я вам напишу код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мой вариант:

```
def players(array):
    pl_lst = ['player1', 'player2', 'NoSuchPlayer'] # Список игроков на проверку 
    for player in pl_lst:
        Flag = False
        for i in range(len(array)):
            if array[i]['nick'] == player:
                array[i]['win'] += 1
                # array[i]['lose'] -=1
                Flag = True
        if Flag == False:
            array.append({'nick': player, 'win': 0, 'lose': 0})
    return array
```

Использование:

```
print players([{
        "nick": "player1",
        "win": 0,
        "lose": 0
    }, {
        "nick": "player2",
        "win": 0,
        "lose": 0
}])
```

Результат:

```
[{
    'nick': 'player1',
    'win': 1,
    'lose': 0
}, {
    'nick': 'player2',
    'win': 1,
    'lose': 0
}, {
    'nick': 'NoSuchPlayer',
    'win': 0,
    'lose': 0
}]
```

**Update** по просьбе автора:

```
def players(array):
    pl_lst = ['player1', 'NoSuchPlayer',
              'player2']  # Список игроков на проверку 
    for player in pl_lst:
        Flag = False
        for i in range(len(array)):
            if player in array[i].keys():
                array[i][player][0] += 1
                array[i][player][1] -= 1
                Flag = True
        if Flag == False:
            array.append({player: [0, 0]})
    return array
```

Использование:

```
print players([{"player1": [0, 0]}, {"player2": [0, 0]}])
```

Результат:

```
[{'player1': [1, -1]}, 
{'player2': [1, -1]}, 
{'NoSuchPlayer': [0, 0]}]
```

Comment: ваш ответ отражает именно то, что и хотел я сделать!
в процессе подумал, что эту информацию,возможно, получится хранить куда проще оставив такой формат:

        `[{"player1":{0:0}},{"player2":{0:0}}]`

как считаете?

Comment: Мне интересно, как бы вы это сделали. И как в таком случае вытащить счет?

Comment: У вас ошибочка, как вы храните победы/поражения? По сути у вас получилось Ключ 0 со значением 0. Правильно будет следующее: `[{"player1": [0, 0]}, {"player2": [0, 0]}]`

Comment: @gasasder Могу обновить ответ для этого варианта.

Comment: было бы здорово для [{"player1": [0, 0]}, {"player2": [0, 0]}]!

Comment: @gasasder обновил ответ